# Boost serializing - adding armadillo matrices that have namespaces to a class

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, namespaces, armadillo

I have successfully serialized armadillo without a class matrices here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <armadillo>
#include <boost/serialization/split_member.hpp>

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_FREE(arma::mat)

namespace boost { 
namespace serialization {

template<class Archive>
void save(Archive & ar, const arma::mat &t, unsigned int version)
{
    ar & t.n_rows;
    ar & t.n_cols;
    const double *data = t.memptr();
    for(int K=0; K<t.n_elem; ++K)
        ar & data[K];
}

template<class Archive>
void load(Archive & ar, arma::mat &t, unsigned int version)
{
    int rows, cols;
    ar & rows;
    ar & cols;
    t.set_size(rows, cols);
    double *data = t.memptr();
    for(int K=0; K<t.n_elem; ++K)
        ar & data[K];
}
}}
int main() {

  arma::mat A = arma::randu<arma::mat>(4,5);

  std::ofstream outputStream;
  outputStream.open("bin.dat");
  std::ostringstream oss;
  boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(outputStream);
  oa & A;
  outputStream.close();

  arma::mat B;
  std::ifstream inputStream;
  inputStream.open("bin.dat", std::ifstream::in);
  boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(inputStream);
  ia & B;
  return 0;
}
```

But my end goal is to have arma matrices within a class, alongside typical data types (int, double, float, etc.) and be able to either serialize everything or specific data from the class. I also got it to work, that the normal data types could be serialized:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/serialization/split_member.hpp>


class Gear {
  public:
    template<typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned int version) { ar & v; }

    void setV (const double& _v) { v = _v; }
    double getV () { return v; }

    void status () { std::cout << "v = " << v << std::endl; }

  private:
    double v;
};

class Car {
  public:
    template<typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned int version) {
      ar & hp;
      ar & x;
    }

    void setHP (const int& _hp) { hp = _hp; }
    void setGear (Gear* _Gear) { x = _Gear; }
    void status () { std::cout << "hp = " << hp << " Gear with v = " << x->getV() <<  std::endl; }

  private:
    int hp;
    Gear *x;
};

int main() {
  // Define new Gear:
  Gear* g = new Gear();
  g->setV(2.5);
  g->status();

  // Expectation is Car sets up the Gear.
  Car c;
  c.setHP(80);
  c.setGear(g);
  //c.status();




  std::ofstream outputStream;
  outputStream.open("bin.dat");
  std::ostringstream oss;
  boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(outputStream);
  oa & c;
  outputStream.close();

  Car b;
  std::ifstream inputStream;
  inputStream.open("bin.dat", std::ifstream::in);
  boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(inputStream);
  ia & b;
  b.status();
  return 0;


}
```

So that works perfect, but I want to include the arma code (essentially) into the class. I tried to put the arma code within the class like such:

```
class Car {
  public:
    template<typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned int version) {
      ar & hp;
      ar & x;
    }

  namespace boost { 
  namespace serialization {

  template<class Archive>
  void save(Archive & ar, const arma::mat &t, unsigned int version)
  {
    ar & t.n_rows;
    ar & t.n_cols;
    const double *data = t.memptr();
    for(int K=0; K<t.n_elem; ++K)
        ar & data[K];
  }

  template<class Archive>
  void load(Archive & ar, arma::mat &t, unsigned int version)
  {
    int rows, cols;
    ar & rows;
    ar & cols;
    t.set_size(rows, cols);
    double *data = t.memptr();
    for(int K=0; K<t.n_elem; ++K)
        ar & data[K];
  }
  } }  

    arma::mat A;// = arma::randu<arma::mat>(4,5);

    void setHP (const int& _hp) { hp = _hp; }
    void setGear (Gear* _Gear) { x = _Gear; }
    void status () { std::cout << "hp = " << hp << " Gear with v = " << x->getV() << A<< std::endl; }

  private:
    int hp;
    Gear *x;
};
```

And then in the int main():

```
  Car c;
  c.setHP(80);
  c.setGear(g);
  c.A = arma::randu<arma::mat>(4,5);
```

After trying to compile the attempt, I am getting the errors:

```
g++ -std=c++11 arma_serial_binary_versuch.cpp -larmadillo -lboost_serialization
arma_serial_binary_versuch.cpp:52:3: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘namespace’                                                     
   namespace boost {                                                                                                                       
   ^                                                                                                                                       
arma_serial_binary_versuch.cpp:121:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input                                                                  
 }                                                                                                                                         
 ^                                                                                                                                         
arma_serial_binary_versuch.cpp: In member function ‘void Car::serialize(Archive&, unsigned int)’:                                          
arma_serial_binary_versuch.cpp:48:12: error: ‘hp’ was not declared in this scope                                                           
       ar & hp;
            ^
arma_serial_binary_versuch.cpp:49:12: error: ‘x’ was not declared in this scope
       ar & x;
            ^
arma_serial_binary_versuch.cpp: At global scope:
arma_serial_binary_versuch.cpp:50:5: error: expected unqualified-id at end of input
     }
```

I've read that it's not possible to work with namespaces within a class but I am unsure of a workaround this. Anyone have any ideas/recommendations?

Comment: To use boost serialization you need to either create methods in your class, such as serialize, or you need to create free function (outside your class). Only the free functions should be inside the boost::serialization namespace.
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60633451/boost-serializing-armadillo-matrices) for a way to serialize armadillo matrices.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out. Just needed to remove the namespace code out of the class.